# Construction of Borel set with given Lebesgue density.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

Let $\alpha \in (0,1)$. How can I construct a Borel set $A$ such that $$\lim_{r \to 0+ } \frac{m(A \cap [-r,r])}{2r}=\alpha$$?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any ideas? Where do they run into difficulties?

Comment: In the case on $R^2$, I've done it by taking $A=\{x:0<\theta<2 \pi \alpha \}$. In this case, I firstly thought something like generalized Cantor set, but the difficulties arises on how can I make them fractal-like structure near $0$..